# error json_decode return NULL

Tags: php, json

i get post **arg**:

```
//var_dump($_POST['arg']);

{\"username\":\"demo\",\"password\":\"demo\",\"language\":\"7\",\"remember\":\"1\",\"recaptcha_response_field\":\"not torkedSe\",\"recaptcha_challenge_field\":\"03AHJ_VutYReMoMIpG755a_BDrIBquklWRSpf0OmMm_HGaIxCwRH1DFwXU2zdSTEprqGi66rAMd0LaewbcNK12Iir2DQTGAA-DzJZ_jjQQ0WP2JLoG3ANr0HdV3glmovv0B67nqejAj01FrtJA3SaulnTh5q6WwttshJnjBKitI6Np1gejMhIwXQo\"}
```

but when i get `json_decode`, i get `NULL`:

```
$Param = json_decode($_POST['arg'], true);

//var_dump($Param); return NULL
```

i also check on errors:

```
var_dump($Param,
$error === JSON_ERROR_NONE,
$error === JSON_ERROR_DEPTH,
$error === JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH,
$error === JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR,
$error === JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX,
$error === JSON_ERROR_UTF8);
```

and get:

```
NULL
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

***Tell me please where error?***

Comment: Remove the input escaping on your string. `{\"username\":...` should be `{"username":...`

Comment: why? in other hosting i use  it code an havent problem... i get it array with function juqery `JSON.stringify` but problrm ony in new hosting..

Comment: Because its not valid JSON. You'll have to check the settings for "Magic Quotes", your hosting environment might be different this time around... http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Comment: @Scuzzy sorry if i not aright, but see - "JSON.stringify method returns a string that contains the converted text to format JSON." how aright decode? first replace `\"` on `"` and than decode or is there another way?

Comment: It really IS the setting of magic quotes. This setting should be OFF! It will be set to off anyways in the current PHP versions and is removed in PHP 5.5, but if you are using an older PHP, your hosting company might have turned it on.

Comment: sorry all - i check config and i see that magic is On - the problem is solved. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove backslashes from string before parsing.

Also check what `json_last_error()` will return. It should help you in the future.

You said that it's problem with your new server. Check `get_magic_quotes_gpc()`. If it's true, you've found problem.

Comment: @learner You didn't show from where you are getting this `$error`. Also show `var_dump` on it directly because it's strange that it doesn't even match "no error".